# Install Modules as Admin

Tags: powershell

I want to install modules using my admin account.  When I used Windows RUN AS A DIFFERENT USER I got the following error message "**you don't have enough rights to install, please login with administrator account**"  Well, I bypassed this by using -Score CurrentUser.  So it works if I do it manually...

I want to automate the process, so I converted my PS1 to EXE
For some reason, when I enter my Admin username, it prompts for my password, but it does not do anything else...  It was loading for like 5 minutes and nothing...

Could someone help me please?

Thank you

```
$userID = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter your Admin Account"
Write-Host $AdminID
runas /user:ent\$AdminID PowerShell


Install-Module -Name PowerShellGet -Force -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser
Install-Module -Name MicrosoftTeams -Scope CurrentUser
Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement -Scope CurrentUser


Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
Import-Module MicrosoftTeams
```

Comment: The `Import-Module` part of the code shouldn't be there since this would be importing the modules on the admin session. As for converting the PS1 to EXE, I would not recommend that. `Start-Process -Verb RunAs -Credential ...` in this case should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out, it should work as long as you supply valid credentials. This will prompt a UAC window before elevating.

Recommended docs if you want to know more on this topic:

- [Start Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.2)
- [about_Powershell.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1)

**Note**, as long as your current user has admin permissions the credential prompt as well as the `Credential = $cred` on the code can be removed, `-Verb RunAs` will elevate the session. If you want to install the modules on *All profiles*, the `-Scope CurrentUser` should be removed.

```
$cred = $Host.UI.PromptForCredential(
    $null, 'Supply Admin Credentials', $null, $null
)

$commands = @'
Install-Module -Name PowerShellGet -Force -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser
Install-Module -Name MicrosoftTeams -Scope CurrentUser
Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement -Scope CurrentUser
'@

$arguments = @{
    FilePath     = 'powershell.exe'
    Verb         = 'RunAs'
    Credential   = $cred
    ArgumentList = @(
        '-ExecutionPolicy ByPass',
        '-Command',
        $commands,
        '-NoExit',
        '-NoProfile'
    )
}

Start-Process @arguments
```